# optimisation advice on value clamping in a loop

Tags: c++, c++11, assembly, c++14, inline-assembly

I have a tight loop exactly like what Chandler Carruth presented in CPP CON 2017:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2EWejmkKlxs
at 25 mins in this video, there is a loop like this:

```
for (int& i:v)
    i = i>255?255:i;
```

where `v` is a vector. This is exactly the same code used in my program which after profiling, proves to take a good amount of time.

In his presentation, Chandler modified the assembly and speed up the loop. My question is, in practice, in a production code, what is the recommended approach to optimise this? Shall we use inline assembly in c++ code? Or like Chandler did, compile C++ code into assembly then optimise the assembler?

An example to optimise the above for loop will be really appreciated, assuming x86 architecture.

Comment: You might want to try something like `std::transform(begin(v), end(v), begin(v), [](int i) { return std::clamp(i, 255, 0); })`, as it allows for better parallelization or vectorization.

Comment: maybe consider where the values are coming from and where do they go, the best optimization is when you dont need that loop at all

Comment: Thanks! @Someprogrammerdude could you please elaborate a bit more on why using std::transform and std::clamp allows for better parallelization or vectorization? I thought the original for loop will be compiled the same way as yours, if not better.

Comment: *'An example [...]'* - in assembler? That would be HW specific, so you'd need to specify target architecture. Otherwise we'll be tied to C++ only optimisations...

Comment: @Aconcagua just clarified that in my question. I'm targeting at x86 machines.

Comment: x86 32 bit or x86-64 (64 bit)? These are somewhat like two different machines... (BTW, I believe there are clamping instructions in MMX or SSE extensions, so depending what is your `v`, maybe you can use intrinsics over it... then again, if `v` is of favourable type, I would expect already your compiler to use those, with enough optimization switches used, so it depends a lot what is `v` and why does it prevent compiler from producing more performant machine code) ... hmmm, thinking about it, this requires [MCVE] for meaningful example of how-to-improve.

Comment: Have you tried to eliminate the branch by bit-twiddling? `y ^ ((x ^ y) & -(x < y))` gives the minimum of `x` and `y`, so use `x=i` and `y=0xff`.

Comment: @Ped7g v is a vector. thanks.

Comment: @MadScientist I'm impressed by your solution but this is rather unreadable - Maybe even more unreadable than assembler code : ) I will give it a try and see how much speedup this can bring.

Comment: @james It is not unusual that heavily optimised code is badly human-readable...

Comment: @james If you are interested in more of [such stuff](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html)...

Comment: @MadScientist: Yuck, just write something the compiler can easily auto-vectorize into [SSE4.1 `pminsd`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pminsd:pminsq) for signed-int clamping, assuming you're targeting SSE4.1.

Comment: Or just watching the video, he's disabling autovectorization so the compiler uses cmp/cmovge.  A conditional select ALU instruction is more efficient than what you'd probably get from that bithack, even with one of the inputs being an immediate.

Comment: @Aconcagua thanks for the link.

Comment: @james `std::vector` is from assembly point of view completely abstract and "undefined" type (undefined as in = not known how many bits and in what constellation will be used by single element). You can't produce assembly for such under-specified type. (EDIT: actually if one assumes you don't do implicit casting, `std::vector<int>` may be assumed, but it's safer to have that explicitly stated) That's why [MCVE] helps a lot with this kind of questions, as everything must be defined enough to get working binary...

Comment: But the most important point is, that with modern C++ compilers and x86-64 target, it's very easy to make some trivial "mistake" in C++ source preventing compiler from using better solution (things related to aliasing rules, memory alignment, etc..). Carefully crafted example showing your actual planned lifecycle of those data and how they will be passed along to the function/etc can help to check all those tricky spots and suggest improvements to the original C++ source, avoiding the assembly for as long as possible. Using assembly in real (not for fun) projects should be one of last options.

Comment: Seems relevant: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/clamp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is, in practice, in a production code, what is the recommended approach to optimise this? Shall we use inline assembly in c++ code? Or like Chandler did, compile C++ code into assembly then optimise the assembler?

For production code you need to consider that the software might be compiled and linked in an automatic build system.

How would you want to apply the code changes to assembler code in such a system? You might apply a diff file, but that might break if if optimisation (or other) settings are changed, if switching to another compiler or ...

Now remaining two options: write the entire function in an assembler file (.s) or have inline assembler code inside the C++ code – the latter possibly with the advantage of keeping related code in the same translation unit.

Still I'd let the compiler generate assembler code *once* – with highest optimisation level available. This code can then serve as a (already pre-optimised) base for your hand-made optimisations, of which the outcome should then be pasted back as inline assembly to the C++ source file or placed into a separate assembly source file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. "How would you want to apply the code changes to assembler code in such a system?" this is exactly where my question is coming from.

Comment: @james: Chandler modified the compiler's asm output because that's an easy way to do a one-off *experiment* to find out whether a change would be useful; compiler-generated asm is usally a good starting point for an optimized loop.  It's *not* a good or even viable way to actually maintain an asm implementation of a loop as part of a program.  Plus it defeats the purpose of having any other functions in the file written in C++ and being available for link-time optimization.

Answer (score 2):

**Chandler modified the compiler's asm output because that's an easy way to do a one-off experiment to find out whether a change would be useful**, *without* doing all the stuff you'd normally want to include an asm loop or function as part of the source code for a project.

Compiler-generated asm is usually a good starting point for an optimized loop, but actually keeping the whole file as-is isn't a good or even viable way to actually maintain an asm implementation of a loop as part of a program.  See @Aconcagua's answer.

Plus it defeats the purpose of having any other functions in the file written in C++ and being available for link-time optimization.

---

**Re: actually clamping:**

Note that Chandler was just experimenting with changes to the non-vectorized code-gen, and disabled unrolling + auto-vectorization.  In real life hopefully you can target SSE4.1 or AVX2 and let the compiler auto-vectorize with [`pminsd`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/PMINSD:PMINSQ.html) or [`pminud`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/PMINUD:PMINUQ.html) for signed or unsigned int clamping to an upper bound.  (Also available in other element sizes.  Or without SSE4.1, just SSE2, maybe you can 2x `PACKSSDW` => [`packuswb`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/packuswb) (unsigned saturation) then unpack with zeros back up to 4 vectors of dword elements.  (If you can't just use an output of `uint8_t[]`!)

And BTW, [in the comments of the video, Chandler said](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2EWejmkKlxs&lc=UgwGVzkWvgJ687jzYJF4AaABAg.8ZZuRtso72u8_kIWoRq8q0) it turns out that he made a mistake and the effect he was seeing wasn't really due to a predictable branch vs. a cmov.  It might have been a code-alignment thing, because changing from `mov %ebx, (%rdi)` to `movl $255, (%rdi)` made a difference!

(AMD CPUs aren't known to have register-read stalls the way P6-family did, should have no trouble hiding the dep chain of a cmov coupling a store to a load vs. breaking it with branch prediction + speculation past a branch.)

---

You very *rarely* would actually want to use a hand-written loop.  Often you can hand-hold and/or trick your compiler into making asm more like what you want, just by modifying the C++ source.  Then a future compiler is free to tune differently for `-march=some_future_cpu`.